# 2 wordpress site same database

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, php, menus

I have twoo websites on worpdress platform:

- http://fian.ro/
- http://nuovafattoria.ro/

On the server there are 2 different folders with same files, same config but one of them has:

```
define('WP_HOME',    'http://nuovafattoria.ro/');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://nuovafattoria.ro/');
```

so is the same database but different url.

I wanna made some changes on one of them, different logo, background so I need a second options table but the others to remain same for both websites.

How can I have different logo, background and settings on the second website?

Comment: Why do you have this set up? What is it trying to achieve?

Comment: Both sites will have the same content? If so this isn't neccesary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into using HyperDB instead.
This would allow you to pull data from several databases while one is replicated as the "master" database.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/hyperdb/

From the description page of the plugin:

> It supports:
>
> - Read and write servers (replication)
> - Configurable priority for reading and writing
> - Local and remote datacenters
> - Private and public networks
>     **- Different tables on different databases/hosts**
> - Smart post-write master reads
> - Failover for downed host
> - Advanced statistics for profiling

Hope this helps you.